# Replace regExp with certain characters (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have having some issues trying to replace a certain group of special characters in a string. Specifically

```
str = 'This is some demo copy[300]this should remove the brackets and the copy 300.'
```

I have been trying to replace it with

```
str.replace(/[300]/g, "<br />");
```

with no such luck. I seem to be getting hung on with the brackets`[]` that also need to be removed. I know that I can remove them  individually, and then replace the 300 but I need to replace the set together.

It should return:

```
This is some demo copy
this should remove the brackets and the copy 300.
```

Any advice would be extremely appreciative as I am relatively new to regular expressions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regular expressions, `[` and `]` have special meaning. You're asking to replace any `3` or `0` that might be found.

Escape the brackets like so:

```
str.replace(/\[300\]/g, "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex for you:

```
/\[300\]/g
```

Brackets in regular expressions language define a character set. In your case you simply need to escape them to make things working.

Comment: That would also replace the bare "300" at the end (since you made the brackets optional), which isn't what the OP is after.

Comment: Hm.. I was sure he wants to replace both, whenever there are brackets or there are not. Most probably I misread. Anyway, if so, just removed `?`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your square brackets.

```
str.replace(/\[300\]/g, "<br />");
```